# rsyslog to external script

Tags: centos, python, rsyslog

Using CentOS I have rsyslog configured to send data to a python script via a shell execute action(^).  I have python 2.7 installed, but when my script is called, the shell environment is referencing python2.4.  Any ideas on how to get the external script to point at the right python version?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, put the absolute path to the correct python binary in your rsyslog.conf.

Comment: tried *.* ^/usr/local/bin/python path_to_script and received "exec: No such file or directory" error.  Isn't there just a way to set the shell it opens to use the right path?

Comment: Did you nest the entire line in single quotes?  double quotes?  `^'/usr/local/bin/python path_to_script'`

Comment: yes.  same error.  In fact, if I stick quotes around an existing script, it throws the error.

The shell that gets created is pretty bare.  I have a test script that writes out the sys.path and os.environ to a file in /tmp and it lists the path as /usr/lib64/python2.4/....  if I run that script from a user, the shell environment has the right paths.  Is there a way to modify the shell that rsyslog starts?

Comment: It likely starts a shell simply as the user for which it's assigned... you can modify their bash profile to adjust the $PATH?  Also, you shouldn't have such a problem with rsyslog.  It should execute the script, and that's it.  My exposure to rsyslog is [this](http://en.doc.centreon.com/Rsyslog) (which I wrote).  I don't use it now/yet in prod, so sorry to sort of blindly lead.